# Get list element name from index

Tags: r, rlang, r-glue

I'm trying to use the following `glue` code to create an informative error message

```
library(rlang)
library(glue)

my_function <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("my_function", x)
}

my_function.default <- function(x) {
  abort(glue(
    "Can't calculate my_function because { deparse(substitute(x)) } is of type ",
    glue_collapse(class(x))
  ))
}
```

Using this test list we see it works:

```
test <- list(
  x = c(1,2,3),
  y = c("one", "two", "three")
)

my_function(test[[1]])
```

```
Error: Can't calculate my_function because test[[1]] is of type numeric
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

But is it possible to use `glue` to have the the error return `x` where it says `test[[1]]` resulting in the error:

`Can't calculate my_function because x is of type numeric`

Comment: I want it to return the name of the list element so if I did my_function(test[[2]]) right now it would return "Can't calculate my_function because y is of type character"

Comment: Do you want the name of the list element

Comment: When you pass in `test[[1]]`, you do not pass in the names as well. You could write code to possibly handle that, but then you'd also have special code for cases like `my_function(test$x)` or `my_function(fun_that_returns_list())` or just `my_function(1:3)` -- what happens in those cases? If you always expect a list, then you might want to specify separate parameters for the list itself and the subset parameter.

Comment: Ah ha interesting, that was my question, how to access the name of the list element when you're already *inside* it I guess that's just not possible?

Comment: it is not possible if it is inside. you can either pass two parameters, one the list and the name and then it would be easier

Comment: It's not possible with any sort of normal evaluation in R. Values are not aware of the fact that they are in lists. It's only the case that lists know their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that digs into an indexing expression to infer the name of the element being indexed. Briefly, it converts expressions that follow the `list[index]` pattern to `names(list)[index]`, while being smart about `list$name` already having the name in the expression.

```
getElementNames <- function(ee) {
    ## Determine if ee is an indexing operation
    eel <- as.list(ee)
    isIdx <- purrr::map_lgl(exprs( `[`, `[[`, `$` ),
                            identical, eel[[1]])

    ## If not, return the expression itself as a string
    if(!any(isIdx)) return( deparse(ee) )

    ## The name may already be in the expression
    if( is.name(eel[[3]]) || is.character(eel[[3]]) )
        return( as.character(eel[[3]]) )

    ## Compose an expression indexing the names
    nms <- eval.parent(expr( names(!!eel[[2]])[!!eel[[3]]] ))

    ## Names might be missing
    `if`( is.null(nms), deparse(ee), nms )
}
```

The function in action:

```
test  <- list(a=4, b=5, c=6)
test2 <- 1:3
ftest <- function(x) abort(glue("Can't calculate {getElementNames(substitute(x))}"))

ftest( test[[2]] )    # index by numeric value
# Error: Can't calculate b

ftest( test$c )       # index by name
# Error: Can't calculate c

ftest( test[["a"]] )  # another way to index by name
# Error: Can't calculate a

i <- 2; j <- 3
ftest( test[i:j] )    # index multiple elements
# Error: Can't calculate b
# * Can't calculate c

ftest( test2[3] )     # index something with no names
# Error: Can't calculate test2[3]

ftest( fun_that_returns_list() )  # non-indexing expression
# Error: Can't calculate fun_that_returns_list()

ftest( 1:3 )                      # another non-indexing expression
# Error: Can't calculate 1:3
```